# Using swagger-ui, how do I make the url dynamic and call the api.yaml file in /storage? #8901

Tags: swagger-ui, vite, laravel-9

I'm using Laravel 9 vite and I can only get Swagger working when api.yaml is in the public folder.

1. How do I change the swagger.js so the api.yaml can be saved in storage/api/docs?
2. How do I make the url dynamic so it uses the APP_URL?
   // swagger.js

import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui'
import 'swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css';
SwaggerUI({
dom_id: '#swagger-api',
url: 'http://localhost/api.yaml',
});

I've tried using these solutions to no eval.

const url: import.meta.env.APP_URL + '/api.yaml'
const url: process.env.APP_URL + '/api.yaml'